# How to run a shell script with a file argument located in the same directory at the script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I would like to run a command with an argument placed in the same directory as the shell script, from a shell script.

example:

```
my_installer.sh:


#!/bin/sh 
sudo dpkg -i --someflags=abcd blah.deb
```

How do I tell `my_installer.sh` where `blah.deb` is ?

I have tried `./blah.deb`  and looked at some env vars... I get an error about file not found.

I am assuming that the user would double-click the script, or run it from home - not cd to the script location.

Comment: It is ... I did not see it ... though I am happy to have received a different answer as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the question: (a) the script is in the same directory as `blah.deb`, and (2) the user will run the script from some unknown other directory.  In that case:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo dpkg -i --someflags=abcd "${BASH_SOURCE[0]%/*}/blah.deb"
```

The shebang line is upgraded to `bash` so that we can use the `BASH_SOURCE` array which tells us the location of the script being executed.

Because this avoids command substitution, it should work even in the pathological case in which the directory name ends with newline characters.

Comment: Just tested... getting error "Bad substitution"... even though the directory name has no special characters

Comment: @Thalia The question is tagged `bash`.  A `Bad substitution` error would indicate that the script was running under another shell, likely `dash` since `dash` is the default shell (`/bin/sh`) on Ubuntu.  To get `bash` features, use the `#!/bin/bash` for the shebang line (if the script is executable) or run the script as `bash script` otherwise.

Comment: The first line in the script was '#!/bin/bash"

Comment: In that case, how was the script run?

Comment: I double-clicked... nothing happened... so I dragged it to the terminal to see its error

Comment: I apologize, the first line was #/bin/sh... changed to bash and it worked

Comment: @Thalia Excellent.  Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can first cd in the script to the script location with

```
cd "$(dirname $0)"
```

or use

```
sudo dpkg -i --someflags=abcd "$(dirname $0)"/blah.deb
```

This works also with /bin/sh being dash instead of bash.